# Execute "class" with multiple input - Python

Tags: python

I have a simplified code here.(Original code is too much to put up)

```
import time
class Stock:

    def __init__(self,  Asset):
        self.Asset = Asset
        self.i_init = 0
        self.i_Ana = 0


    def Initiate_sequence(self):
        self.i_init +=1

        """One Execute Once"""
        print("Initiate Program")

    def Analysis(self):


        """Need to Execute every 60 Seconds"""
        self.i_Ana += 1

        print(self.Asset)
        print(f"Init {self.i_init}")
        print(f"Ana {self.i_Ana}")
```

I want to execute the program like this (This execute with no problem):

```
stock_one =  Stock("stock_one")
stock_one.Initiate_sequence()

stock_two =  Stock("stock_two")
stock_two.Initiate_sequence()

stock_three =  Stock("stock_three")
stock_three.Initiate_sequence()


while True:
    stock_one.Analysis()
    stock_two.Analysis()
    stock_two.Analysis()
    time.sleep(10)
```

But, there more than 3 stocks, so I need "for loop" to iterate over this Assets list

I did:

```
Assets = ["stock_one", "stock_two", "stock_three"]
for asset in Assets:
    asset = Stock(asset)
    asset.Initiate_sequence() # Initialize all the assets

while True:                   # Loop each asset analysis module every 10 seconds
    for asset in Assets:
        asset.Analysis()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Now it gives error

```
Initiate Program
Initiate Program
Initiate Program
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-420b1a82343b> in <module>
      6 while True:                   # Loop each asset analysis module every 10 seconds
      7     for asset in Assets:
----> 8         asset.Analysis()
      9     time.sleep(10)
     10 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Analysis'
```

Any idea how to fix this? Much appriciated.

---

With Daniel's answer I did this

```
Assets = ["stock_one", "stock_two", "stock_three"]
stocks = map(Stock, Assets)

while True:
    for stock in stocks:
        stock.Analysis()
    time.sleep(10)
```

For some reason it stuck, and does not keep executing for no reason, Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to overwrite your loop variable `asset`, which doesn't work in Python.

If you check your variable `Assets` after casting `asset = Stock(asset)`, you'll see that it's just the strings and not the `Stock` instances you were trying to create. That's the reason you get the `'str' object has no attribute 'Analysis'` error.

Instead, I'd do the following:

```py
# Variables and class methods/properties should be lower-case
# Only classes are upper case
assets = ["stock_one", "stock_two", "stock_three"]

stocks = list(map(Stock, assets))
# The line above is (mostly) equivalent to
# stocks = [Stock(asset) for asset in assets]
# or to
# stocks = []
# for asset in assets:
#   stocks.append(Stock(asset))

while True:
  for stock in stocks:
    stock.analysis()
  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: for some reason it stuck, and does not keep executing for no reason, Any ideas? (This analysis module needs to execute all together and then sleep, I changed only a bit)

Comment: I had mistakenly put the sleep-statement in the inner loop, not the outer one (it's corrected now). Could that be the issue?

Comment: I also noticed that the generator I used to create `stocks` doesn't work if we iterate over `stocks` multiple times (fixed now).